# Is "Process terminated by signal (11)" always related to NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, segmentation-fault

I am tracking a bug in my project. From time to time, my app gets killed and in the logcat there is always the following line:

`D/Zygote  (   xx): Process xxxx terminated by signal (11)`

I have been searching about this error and I always find mentions to `NDK`.

I am developing a project that uses a third-party C library. I do not know the library in great detail, but I can tell you that it does some network communication with a server. In my project there are several `Services`, some of which use this library.

So my question is, does this error always imply that the problem comes from the C library?

If not, could you give me examples of Java code in Android, that could cause this error as well?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: By the way, in the logcat output there is no stack trace before the previous line.

Comment: isn't signal 11 repirted earlier ijn the log? IIRC this _process terminated_ message is the last in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, SIGSEGV was reported before in your log. It may be quite a while earlier than the final message. This is an actual snapshot of one of such crashes in my logs:

```
01-29 16:00:39.124 F/libc    ( 3033): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000002c (code=1)
... many more ...
01-29 16:00:48.367 D/Zygote  (  116): Process 3033 terminated by signal (11)
```

You can see that it took almost 10 sec for Zygote to report process termination after the fatal signal was received. Your milage may vary.

The actual reasons for SIGSEGV may be within the third-party C library, or in your Java, or in the way you call the C library. Note, for example, that it's forbidden to make most of JNI calls while a Java Exception is raised.

Comment: I definitively don't have a SIGSEGV reported previously in my logcat. Wouldn't the absence of a stack trace be a sign of a non Java/Android error? I've never seen an application being killed without any logcat message before.

Comment: Neither have I. But maybe the message went "behind the horizon", or never made it to the adb? I have encountered some devices that were configured so that the system components generated so much log, that some of my app messages were simply lost. Anyway, what is important that you may need to look back 10 sec or more to find the source of the crash.

Comment: Some versions of Android have an issue where, if native code fiddles with the signal handler and strips the `SA_SIGINFO` flag, the signal handler itself crashes and you get zero feedback in the log.  I caught a GLES shader compiler doing this on one platform.  See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/f84bc8d6f6368f1c846124a8168761ee8cc589c0 .  I don't know if that's what's happening here, but it's a possibility.